# Set SelectedValue in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn or DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, selectedvalue, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I would like to set a value to the ComboBox in the DataGridView. I already have changed the comboBoxItems, I just want to select one of them. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Can you give us some example code?  specifically, at what point you want to add in the "Select Item at this point".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved my problem... I'm gonna post the way I did and hoppefully someone will find this answer too.

```
   dgrDetalle.DataSource = dataTable("select * from yourTable");
   DataTable dtCombo = dataTableCombo("select COL_ID DETOC_COL_FK,COL_DESCRIPCION from yourTable2");
   string[] strColumns = new string[] { "COL_DESCRIPCION" };
   MultiColumnDictionary map = new MultiColumnDictionary(dtCombo, "DETOC_COL_FK", strColumns, 0);
   dgrDetalle.Cols["DETOC_COL_FK"].DataMap = map;
```

As you can see the class that save my life is MultiColumnDictionary.

Note: The combobox items must be loaded in a different DatatTable than the DataTable that is gonna load directly in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Comboboxes only actually exist as controls when they are being edited, and therefore don't have a selected item property.
You can simply set the `Value` property of the cell to the item you want selected, or alternitively, you can set a default value by setting the property:

`DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already did what you say, I only can access to the comboBox.selectedValue when I am editing it, buy what I want to do now is retrieve some data from a database, and I do not have any problem with the DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Value Assignation, the data are loaded to the DataGridView, but not the same situation for the DataGridViewComboBoxCell. I even tried with DataGridViewComboBoxCell.Value and this didn't work. Hope someone can help me. Anyway Thank You so much!!

Comment: What type of value are you assigning? A string or an integer?

Comment: It is an Integer... I´m using Oracle, so the data type from the database is "number", and when I make the query I take the value from that field on the table and I handle it as an Integer.

Comment: The error that shows a Dialod is this: 

The following exception ocurred in the DataGridView:

System.FormatException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

Comment: the value type must be a string.

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work... this is what I got

DataGridViewComboBoxCell idProduct;
idProducto = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
idProduct.Value = detail[0].IdProduct.ToString();
//Detail is an object from a class that i've created